# How to fill a list or view via the windows shell (iDropTarget)

Tags: c#, treeview, windows-shell, shell-extensions

I have a little WinForms application with a tree view.  I can drag and drop files and directories in, and I can start the program by dropping one or more files or directories on it / using the commandline (args).  What I can’t figure out is how to do the shell extension to allow multiple sections from the explorer to start it.

Does anyone have a small sample illustrating filling some type of list or view using a shell extension and the  GUI and / or from the command line?

I would much appreciate the help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not exactly the answer toiDropTarget, this link provides the solution to my problem:
[The Weekly Source Code 31- Single Instance WinForms and Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode31SingleInstanceWinFormsAndMicrosoftVisualBasicdll.aspx)